# IOT Hub to Cosmos DB / Integration Fails

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I can't believe I can't find any documentation on correcting this error when enabling Synapse link from a Cosmos DB.  I created the DB to receive message from IOT hub using a Custom endpoint (pointing to Cosmos db), and then added a message route to send messages to cosmos.  Worked like a charm, until I tried to enable the Synaspe link, and got this error:
[image]

It looks like you enable the backup mode to either 7 days or 30 days, and I can't seem to turn it off.

I don't want to recreate the DB, as the messages are continuing to flow in.

I also tried to create a new container, based on an existing container - but that resulted in this:
[image]

And both options of the Analytical Store are greyed out.... at this point Azure SQL is looking better and better..

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Synapse Link and Continuous backup option are currently not allowed in the same database account. Users must select one of these two characteristics, and their choice cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction#backup)

> Synapse Link is not available in the same database user at this time in Continuous backup mode. Users must select one of these two characteristics, and their choice cannot be reversed.

Unfortunately, your ask is not possible to use  `Azure Synapse Link` with **continuous backup mode** it is not fully compatible with it and also we cant change the backup mode to Periodic it is not reversible.

[image]

The only solution is to create a new cosmos db with `Periodic backup mode` default and then enable synapse link in that cosmos db because only periodic backup mode is available with synapse link, and we can use them together in a single database.

You can raise the feature request to work on both `continuous backup mode` and `synapse link` together [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/3002b3be-0d25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858).

Comment: I would update the documentation that a continuous backup means that Synapse cannot be used.  The error message should also state, or have a reference to, this section of the documentation.  As I have 400,000+ entries and the DB is tied to a production environment, I now have to navigate the re-creation of Cosmos while production is in flight!